# lme4: How to specify estimated parameters for a specific model in the lmer function?

Tags: r, lme4, nlme, random-effects

I have a longitudinal dataset for plant growth, where each row represents an individual plant's measurements over multiple seasons. The variables in the dataset include

- "id" (individual plant ID),
- "season" (the seasons that the plant experienced),
- "td" (the duration of time between measurements),
- "Lt" (plant height at a measurement), and
- "Lt_1" (plant height at the previous measurement).

Here's an example of the dataset:

```
library(lme4)

df <- data.frame(
  id = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e"),
  season = c("s1", "s1", "s2", "s3", "s3", "s4", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s3", "s3", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s3", "s3", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s3", "s3", "s4", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s3", "s3", "s4"),
  td = c(59, 95, 210, 134, 62, 169, 60, 96, 208, 134, 62, 60, 94, 210, 133, 63, 59, 99, 206, 134, 62, 169, 59, 122, 182, 134, 62, 171),
  Lt = c(40, 44, 72, 84, 87, 101, 40, 44, 66, 75, 77, 43, 47, 67, 79, 80, 38, 42, 64, 75, 76, 80, 44, 47, 69, 79, 80, 99),
  Lt_1 = c(35.5, 40, 44.5, 72, 84.2, 87, 35, 40.1, 43.8, 65.9, 75.4, 40.8, 43, 47, 66.8, 78.7, 34, 37.5, 41.9, 63.6, 75.2, 76.5, 39.2, 43.5, 46.9, 68.7, 79.4, 80.5)
)

head(df)

> head(df)
  id season  td    Lt Lt_1
1  a     s1  59  40.0 35.5
2  a     s1  95  44.5 40.0
3  a     s2 210  72.0 44.5
4  a     s3 134  84.2 72.0
5  a     s3  62  87.0 84.2
6  a     s4 169 101.4 87.0
```

Now, I am attempting to fit a model to estimate the plant growth using the previous measurement (Lt_1) and the duration of time (td) as predictors. The model formula is as follows:

```
formula = Lt ~ 150*((1 + ((150/Lt_1)^(1/p)-1)*exp(-k*td/365))^(-p))
```

**Question #1**: how to specify the parameters to be estimated in the lmer function?

I want to include a random effect in the parameter "k" for "id" in the model. In the `nlme` function from the `nlme` package, I can explicitly specify the parameters to be estimated like this.

```
library(nlme)
model <- nlme(formula,
                  fixed = k + p ~ 1,
                  random = k ~ 1,
                  groups = ~ id,
                  data = df,
                  start = c(k = 0.2,
                            p = 1))
```

However, I have no idea how to achieve the same with the `lme4::lmer` function. A lot of examples with `lmer` use a generic function to estimate the parameter like [this][1]. Can anybody help me how to do this using a specific function?

**Question #2**: how to estimate "k" for each season?

I want to estimate the parameter "k" separately for each season in the dataset. I assume that each season may have different "k" values, such as "k1" for "s1" and "k2" for "s2". How can I specify this in the code using the `lmer` function? I tried something like this but did not work even with `nlme` function.

```
formula2 = Lobs ~ 150*((1 + ((150/Lt_1)^(1/p)-1)*exp(-k*season*td/365))^(-p))
model <- nlme(formula2,
                  fixed = k + p ~ 1,
                  random = k ~ 1,
                  groups = ~ id,
                  data = df,
                  start = c(k = 0.2,
                            p = 1))
```

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want with `lmer`.  Is there a reason that `nlme` *won't* do for what you want?

Comment: @BenBolker, the only reason why I wanted to do this with `lmer` is that the `lme4` package provide more flexible features than the `nlme` and I thought it is more worth to learn it. I dont have any specific reasons to stick with `lmer` for this particular model fitting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lmer` simply won't work for what you want to do, and `nlmer` is unfortunately rather immature — if you can make it work, `nlme` is probably still the best choice. I *think* you want something like this, but the data set you've given is a bit too small to figure out if the problems I'm having are due to the setup or to the limitations of the data.

It is almost always worthwhile to set up a function that can provide the gradient as well as the objective function:

```r
dfun <- deriv(formula[-2],  ## RHS of formula
      namevec = c("p", "k"),
      function.arg = c("k", "p", "Lt_1", "td"))
## test
dfun(p = 1, k = 0.2, Lt_1 = 35, Lt = 40)
## [1] 35.74052
## attr(,"gradient")
##              p      k
## [1,] 0.4133755 3.7294
```

Something like this (I prefer to specify grouping variables on the right side of a bar (`|`) rather than via the `groups` argument):

```r
library(nlme)
model <- nlme(Lt ~ dfun(k, p, Lt_1, td),
              fixed = list(p ~ 1, k ~ season),
              random = k ~ 1| id,
              data = df,
              start = list(fixed = c(1, 0.2, 0, 0, 0))
              )
```

This gets to

> Error in nlme.formula(Lt ~ dfun(k, p, Lt_1, td), fixed = list(p ~ 1, k ~  :
> step halving factor reduced below minimum in PNLS step

but it's hard to know in general whether this means there's something wrong with the model setup/starting values/etc. *or* whether the example data set is too small to work — could be either.

Comment: This data is just an example. My actual data has over 100 individuals. I tried your code, but ended up getting exactly the same error. Is this perhaps the computational problem? Should I use ADMB/TMB to find the parameters? I appreciate your advice.

Comment: It's possible that `nlme` could be made to work, I'm not sure. Either coding it in TMB *or* using nonlinear fits in `brms` (neither of which is a picnic) would be the most likely to work in the long run ...

Comment: thank you for your commennts. I'll try this with brms or TMB

Comment: @Bon Bolker, Seasonal effect model did not work perheps because the data has too small sample size. When I tried it with the data that has more samples, it did work. The reproducible example is shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76632999/error-in-anova-error-in-getresponseformulael-form-must-be-a-two-sided/76633075#76633075

Comment: OK. If a question helped you solve a problem, it's courteous to up-vote it and/or accept it ...

Comment: Yes. I did it. Thank you so much